# What is the difference between "another two" "two more" and "two other"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, semantics

Like I said

> another two (or)
>   there are two more (or)
>   two other people were arrested

Do they have different meanings or implications?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference. "Another" is ambiguous. It can mean "different" or "additional". By contrast, "more" (as in "two more people were arrested") can mean "additional" but cannot mean "different". So if you mean "additional", it would be better to use "more", because "more" avoids that ambiguity.

Comment: It is mean "other" only mean "different"? If I am in a shoes store, I have tried on a pair, but I don't like it, I want assistant to give me a different style or color one, which word should I use? Please take me another one or any other one? Or if I just want a brand new pair of the shoe, should I say another one or the other one?

Answer (score 1):

The leading "There are" isn't required, and essentially no difference exists between the following sentences:

> Two more people were arrested.
>
> Two other people were arrested.
>
> Another two people were arrested.

Since only humans can be arrested, the same meaning can be conveyed even more briefly as follows:

> Two more were arrested.
>
> Two others were arrested.
>
> Another two were arrested.

Note that "other people" changes to "others" in the second example (because "other" as a pronoun is countable, unlike "more").